# sortablejs does not work properly with local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, sortablejs

I'm using the sortablejs library to enable the reordering of my list and to save the order in the local storage. I use console.log to check what happens during the 'get' and 'set' sections, and they work correctly. However, when I refresh the page, it completely ignores the local storage and displays the list in the following format: '1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|7by|1mv'. I can understand where this array comes from, but I can't figure out why it completely ignores the saved order in the local storage every time I refresh the page.

```
// Sortablejs

//obtenemos por ID la seccion en la que se encuentra la lista
const lista = document.getElementById('grilla');
//creamos la lista y aplicamos clases para cada accion
Sortable.create(lista, {
    animation: 200,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "drag",
    ghostClass: "fantasma",
    group: "board",
    store: {
         //obtenemos el orden de la lista
         get: function (sortable) {
            var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group.name);
            console.log(order);
            return order ? order.split('|') : [];
        },
        //guardamos el orden la lista
        set: function (sortable) {
            var order = sortable.toArray();
            console.log(order);
            localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group.name, order.join('|'));
        }
    }
});
```

I already tried renaming the variable where I store the list order. I added console.log in both the 'get' and 'set' sections, and both work perfectly. However, upon refreshing the page, the displayed order is equivalent to this: '1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|7by|1mv', disregarding the variable from the local storage that does correctly contain the previous state of the list.
i need help to get it working, also i notised that when i disable the get and set part of the code it set te correct initial order which is '7by|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv|1mv'

Comment: Could you provide some HTML / CSS in addition to the JS so we can re-create the issue for testing and debugging?

Comment: yeah totally sorry that I didn t post it on the question, I can give u the repository with the code: https://github.com/dest3/weather-app

Comment: I've tested the latest version at this time, and got the same result; it is storing and retrieving properly, but not sorting correctly when loading. At this point, I'd chalk it up to a bug in sortable.js.

Comment: sad... well im moving on then, im thinking now how to achive the sortable efect on my own whit vanilla js thx for the reply <3